# How to pull ACR image from k3s pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-container-registry, coredns

I have customized the coredns image and pushed it to my azure container registry (ACR). 
Now in default coredns pod that is coming after k3s installation, I want to use `my_azure_acr_repo/proj/customize-coredns:latest` image **instead of** `rancher/coredns-coredns:1.8.3`. So I edited the coredns deployment `kubectl edit deploy coredns -n kube-system` and replaced my acr image with rancher one. But now coredns pod is not able to pull my acr image and giving error in pod description:

```
Failed to pull image "my_azure_acr_repo/proj/customize-coredns:latest": rpc error:
code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "my_azure_acr_repo/proj/customize-coredns:latest": 
failed to resolve reference "my_azure_acr_repo/proj/customize-coredns:latest": failed to 
authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

How can I authenticate acr image, so that pod should pull it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your container is not authorized to pull image from your private ACR.

First you've to create secret so that you can access your ACR, then pass that secret in your deployment using `imagePullSecrets`

you can create secret by this command, make sure to replace your credential variables

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <name> --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
```

For ACR it will be something like this

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regkey --docker-server=https://myregistry.azurecr.io --docker-username=ACR_USERNAME --docker-password=ACR_PASSWORD --docker-email=ANY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

your deployment spec

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: foo
      image: janedoe/awesomeapp:v1
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regkey
```

More info related to this.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod